# Instagram media.json How to add them to exif?

Tags: metadata, json, exif, exiftool

I get my photos out of Instagram and i get zip file with all the photos what i have there but they dosnt have any exif data on them.

The zip file has also a json file called media.json where all these important metadata are. So is there any ways to get the metadata to these photos exif?

Exiftool can import things from files to exif but first i need to know what kind of format the metadata file has to be?

This is a example of a what the instagram media.json file content is and what kind of format:

```
{
   "photos": [
      {
         "caption": "#nautitaan #kesä2019",
         "taken_at": "2019-06-08T03:30:25",
         "location": "Jokioinen",
         "path": "photos/201906/b65bbda42ba74424a9d7be0c5163f78d.jpg"
      },
      {
         "caption": "#lupanauttia #kesä2019",
         "taken_at": "2019-06-07T07:42:38",
         "location": "Jokioinen",
         "path": "photos/201906/29fb24838136a1e80439ad7dcae00b4f.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

I only need these `taken_at` entries, all the other things are just plus.

Comment: This seems like a question for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exiftool can read JSON files.  If you run the command `exiftool -g1 -a -s` on your example JSON file, you will get a list of tag names you can use to copy into your image file.  Using your example, the result would be

```
[JSON]          PhotosCaption                   : #nautitaan #kesä2019, #lupanauttia #kesä2019
[JSON]          PhotosLocation                  : Jokioinen, Jokioinen
[JSON]          PhotosPath                      : photos/201906/b65bbda42ba74424a9d7be0c5163f78d.jpg, photos/201906/29fb24838136a1e80439ad7dcae00b4f.jpg
[JSON]          PhotosTaken_at                  : 2019-06-08T03:30:25, 2019-06-07T07:42:38
```

The problem now is that because there are multiple items for each tag name. Exiftool tool is very flexible about how it reads numbers for time stamps (see [exiftool FAQ 5](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q5)), so if the first entry is the correct one, you can simply use
`exiftool -TagsFromFile FILE.Json "-DateTimeOriginal<PhotosTaken_at" FILE.jpg`

If you want to use the second entry, you can use the [`-listitem` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#listItem-INDEX).
`exiftool -listitem 1 -TagsFromFile FILE.Json "-DateTimeOriginal<PhotosTaken_at" FILE.jpg`
Note that the list index starts at 0, so to get the second item, you would index #1.

To bulk copy, assuming that the base filename of the json file is the same as the image file and in the same directory, you could use this command
`exiftool -TagsFromFile %d%f.Json "-DateTimeOriginal<PhotosTaken_at" /path/to/image/files/`

This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.  If this command is run under Unix/Mac, reverse any double/single quotes to avoid bash interpretation.